What was the first movie to depict a scene where a character makes it appear as if they are using another character as a human shield?
In Fast X (2023), Letty meets Tess at an undisclosed location:

Tess: Okay. First, let's get you out of this cell. It's gonna hurt.
Letty: Hmm?
Then Tess stabs Letty in the shoulder and then places Letty's arm
around  her own neck, making it appear as if Letty is using Tess as a
human shield.
Tess: Work with me.

What was the first movie to depict a scene where a character makes it appear as if they are using another character as a human shield?

I suppose Blazing Saddles doesn't count?

Gonna be waaaay earlier than that. Movies have been around for 140 years or so. Certainly any early movie with a jailbreak/prisonbreak might have such a scene. Trying to identify the first of such a ubiquitous idea will be nigh on impossible.

Please clarify if by "makes it appear as if" you mean a ruse where a character (like Tess in your example) is pretending to be used as a human shield? Or do you mean any ordinary depiction of a (helpless, unwilling) human shield?
